# Blitz++ arrays as keys for maps

Tags: c++, stl, blitz++

I am trying to use blitz++ arrays, since I understand they generally offer higher performance than other forms of arrays. Is it possible to use blitz++ arrays as keys in a map? Trying

```
#include <map>
#include <blitz/array.h>
using namespace std;
map<blitz::Array<int,1>,int> testmap;
blitz::Array<int,1> B(3);
B = 1,2,3;
testmap.insert(make_pair(B,2));
```

does not compile.  Here's the error:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/string:50:0,
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h: In member function ‘bool
>   std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp =
>   blitz::Array]’:
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h:236:22: error: cannot convert
>   ‘blitz::BzBinaryExprResult,
>   blitz::Array >::T_result {aka
>   blitz::_bz_ArrayExpr, blitz::FastArrayIterator, blitz::Less > >}’ to
>   ‘bool’ in return

Is this a matter of requiring a definition of the `<` operator, and if so, can/should I define it myself?

**ANSWER**

As suggested by Jimmy Thompson, a possible solution is to define:

```
struct MyComparison 
{
bool operator() (const blitz::Array<int, 1> &lhs, const blitz::Array<int, 1> &rhs) const 
    {
        if (lhs.size() < rhs.size()) {return true;}
        else if (lhs.size() > rhs.size()) {return false;}
    else
        {
        for (int i=0; i<lhs.size(); i++)
            {
            if (lhs(i)<rhs(i)) {return true;}
            else if(lhs(i)>rhs(i)) {return false;}
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then

```
map<blitz::Array<int,1>,int, MyComparison> testmap;
```

Comment: When you say it "does not work" it is very important to say how it does not work.

Comment: I edited in the compiler error. I really don't know what it means though.

Comment: You are right. I edited the namespace std in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `std::map` documentation states that keys are compared using `std::less` by default. This just calls `<` and expects a return of `true` or `false`.

In order for you to use Blitz arrays as a key, you need to do one of the following:

1. Create your own comparison function, like `std::less`, which returns a boolean value stating whether one Blitz array is 'less' than the other (how you choose to determine this is up to you). Assuming you made this function and called it `MyComparison`, you would then create your map as follows `map<blitz::Array<int,1>, int, MyComparison> testmap;`.

   ```
   struct MyComparison
   {
       bool operator() (const blitz::Array<int, 1> &lhs, const blitz::Array<int, 1> &rhs) const
       {
           // Blitz array comparison
       }
   };
   ```
2. Wrap your Blitz array type (`blitz::Array<int,1>`) in another object, overloading the `<` operator for that given object and then performing your comparison in there. For example:

   ```
   class MyArrayWrapper
   {
       blitz::Array<int, 1> contents;

   public:
       // Constructor, etc.

       bool operator<(const MyArrayWrapper &rhs) const
       {
           // Blitz array comparison
       }
   };
   ```

Then in your current file.

```
    std::map<MyArrayWrapper,int> testmap;
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. I chose version 1, since it seems the most lightweight solution. I'll edit my solution into the question. 

I'm not seeing how to use an stl style iterator in the Blitz++ documentation, so my solution might not be the most efficient. The implementation is lexicographic. If you see any way to make it more efficient, I'd love to know.